# Ember transitionTo queryParams not updating the model or URL

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-query-params

I am trying to use `queryParams` to update and refresh the model.  I've set it up the action to use `route-action` because the change event that's firing the action is within a component.  I've installed `ember-route-action-helper` and the change event is working correctly, but the `transitionTo` is not being updated.

In `filter-list.hbs`

```
<input type="checkbox"
  class="filter-checkbox inp-{{value.filterValueId}}"
  value="{{value.filterValueId}}"
  onchange={{route-action "updateQuery" value.filterValueId list.filterId}}>
```

In `routes/results.js`

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({

queryParams: {
  status: {
    refreshModel:true
  },
  owner: {
    refreshModel:true
  }
},

params: null,

model(params) {
  this.set('params', params);
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    result: this.store.query('result', params),
    filter: this.store.findAll('filter'),
    params: params,
  });
},

setupController(controller, model) {
  this._super(...arguments);
  controller.set('result', model.result);
  controller.set('filter', model.filter);
  controller.set('params', model.params);
},

actions: {
  newParams(data){
    console.log("Received", data);
  },
  updateQuery: function() {
    //I make a URL string here from multiple checkboxes
    //and parse the URL string as a JSON object which is
    //modeled the same as a normal queryParameter
    let newParams = JSON.parse('{"' + decodeURI(urlString).replace(/"/g, '\\"').replace(/&/g, '","').replace(/=/g,'":"') + '"}')
    console.log(newParams);
    this.transitionTo({queryParams: {newParams}});
  }
}
```

So, I first pull the `params` from the URL and send them down to fetch the results and also populate a filter list (list of checkboxes with filter names).  Every time I click on a filter, if it sees the checkbox has changed, it fires the `updateQuery` action under the route using `route-action`.

The action runs (and I get the correct `newParams` output in the console.  The line that's not working is `this.transitionT()`.  The transition is not doing anything whatsoever.  It's not updating the model, it's not changing the URL, nothing.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering, I figured this out.

Right now, I'm sending `{queryParams: {newParams}}` to the `transitionTo` function.  But this was turning `newParams` into a key where the object it held was then the value, instead of using `newParams` as a full object.

I've changed this to `{queryParams: newParams}` so now it uses the variable as an object, rather than a key.

`this.transitionTo({queryParams: newParams});`